# How can I access a custom variable in the SceneDelegate from the ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mac-catalyst

I know how to access the scene delegate:

```
self.view.window.windowScene.delegate
```

And the window:

```
UIScene *scene = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes] allObjects] firstObject];

if ([scene.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIWindowSceneDelegate)]) {
    
    UIWindow *window = [(id <UIWindowSceneDelegate>)scene.delegate window];
}
```

But both methods assume I haven't made any changes to the SceneDelegate.h/.m file.

I have created a custom toolbar and I don't know how to access it from the viewController:

**SceneDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SceneDelegate : UIResponder <UIWindowSceneDelegate, NSToolbarDelegate>

@property (strong) NSToolbar *mainToolbar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow * window;

@end
```

I'm using the NSToolbar because it's a Mac Catalyst app that can run on macOS also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But both methods assume I haven't made any changes to the SceneDelegate.h/.m file.

#### Why is this happening?

Because the code you have provided returns an instance of `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. But you are looking for the object of type `SceneDelegate` to access its interface. So you have to cast it to the desired interface.

#### How can I resolve this then?

So you can access it anywhere like:

```
SceneDelegate.shared.myCustomProperty
```

By defining a simple class method:

```
+ (SceneDelegate *)shared {
    return (SceneDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes.allObjects.firstObject;
}
```

<sub>**Note**: Don't forget to import `SceneDelegate.h` and add the `shared` property to its interface.</sub>

---

<sub>You can also just cast it inline like `(SceneDelegate *)self.view.window.windowScene.delegate`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can check wether the object is kind of the desired class:

```
UIScene *scene = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes] allObjects] firstObject];
if ([scene.delegate isKindOfClass:SceneDelegate.class]) {
    SceneDelegate *delegate = (SceneDelegate *)scene.delegate;
    NSToolbar *toolbar = delegate.mainToolbar;
}
```